# How to rescue my lost APFS partitions

Tags: macos, high-sierra

My Disk is 500 GB, and APFS Physical Storage and AppleAPFSMedia are 300GB, can't run First Aid on both.

Currently I can login to macOS High Serria(199GB partition) on which I post this.

There was a system(macOS high serria) and a lot data on that 300GB partition, I can't just erase it, How can I rescue that partition ?

details as below:

[image]. 
[image]. 
[image]. 
[image]. 
[image]

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                     SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                      209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2          301.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1          199.0 GB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                     SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                       +199.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s3
   1:                APFS Volume High Sierra              51.8 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                  42.1 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                 1.0 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                       4.3 GB     disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                     SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                       +ERROR      disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
```

Thanks !

Comment: Sorry - what does rescue mean and which Volumes do you wish to rescue? (Also - you have a backup of your data already, right?!!?)

Comment: sorry, I've edited my question

Comment: no backup of data, I want to rescue data on that 300GB partition. I tried testdisk and diskdrill. but to no avail.

Comment: there was a system on that 300GB partition, I think if I can fix that partition and can login to that system, I can save my data

Comment: What happens if you select the grayed-out partition and click on "Mount"? Also, please show output from "diskutil list" so that we can see what's in the lost 300 GB partition.

Comment: The problem with APFS is that no third party disk utilities support it yet. If it were HFS+, I'd tell you to run Disk Warrior to try to repair, and if that failed, run Data Rescue to recover the data. But in this case, if you don't have time machine, you may be S.O.L., unless you can park the drive somewhere and wait for support to come to more utilities.

Comment: Long shot, but what does holding 'Option' at boot time show? Just your current partition?

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann hi, click mount on 'APFS Physical Store disk0s2', no response. mount button is gray on AppleAPFSMedia.

Comment: @Ian yes, only High serria patition

Comment: Oh dear. You might have lost that partition.

Comment: How did you lose the APFS volumes on disk0s2?

Answer (score 3):

- Run Disk Utility from Recovery Mode
- On Reboot, press <kbd>Cmd-R</kbd>
- Open **Disk Utility**.
- Select your partition one by one and hit repair a couple of times.

If you have another Mac, you can mount your MacBook partition using Target Disk Mode. Connect both Macs with Thunderbolt/USB-C cable. Reboot your MacBook, then immediately **press and hold <kbd>T</kbd>** while it starts up. Hopefully your APFS partition will show up. Note: Both Macs should be using APFS volume.

Answer (score 1):

Download the program [APFS Capture](http://biskus.com). (I'm the author - just run it as a trial, no need to purchase it)

Can that list your files on the "lost" partition? If so, we know that the data is not lost, at least, and can think of other means to rescue it.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I followed the manual, but i can't recover my files because the partition is encrypted, Can i reach out for u with diskus support email  ?

Comment: Yes, write to me using the given support email.